# Using a variable for getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox that is being echoed by PHP. So, the id of the checkbox will be dynamic.

So, I would like use a variable for `document.getElementById()`.

Below is my PHP code:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='edit$count' value='1' onclick='test($count)'></td>";
```

Then here is my Javascript code

```
function test(v)
    {
        var edit = "edit" + v;


        if(document.getElementById(edit).checked==true){
            alert(edit);
        }
    }
```

However, when I clicked on the checkbox, there is no alert.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: $count is a variable that will keep increasing by +1 on every loop.

Comment: What is `$count` at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: There is no `id` in the check box but `name` instead.

Comment: you shouldnt care about your php code, but you should care what html it generates. right click > view html source. you will see your problem.

Comment: it starts with 1. This is because I don't know how many checkboxes are going to be generated. So, I will need a way to give name and id to the checkboxes.

Comment: I think what is happening is the click event calls the listener and THEN sets checked to true. Did you try unchecking the box? I don't think the variable has anything to do with it in any case...

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks to @SheikhHeera

Comment: Oh wait. Right @SheikhHeera the name is set but not the ID. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either replace `document.getElementById` with `document.getElementsByName[]` or change your `name` attribute in your HTML to `id`s. You're not using `id` attributes in your HTML which is why `getElementById` is returning `null`:

```
if (document.getElementsByName(edit)[v].checked == true) { ... }
```

You also don't need the `== true` as the boolean context of the if statement will take care of it:

```
if (document.getElementsByName(edit)[v].checked) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because you seted `name` of the input, and then trying to get it by `id`. Change `name='$count'` to `id='$count'`. And for the future: almost any browser provide Developer Tools with debugger, please, feel free to use it to investigate JavaScript problems.